# SQL Where Clause with If (or Case) statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    WORKORDER.WONUM,
    WORKORDER.WO3, 
    WORKORDER.DESCRIPTION WO_DESC, 
    WORKORDER.WORKTYPE, 
    WORKORDER.STATUS, 
    WORKORDER.WOPRIORITY, 
    (case when WORKORDER.CUSTREQ1=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) WO18, 
    WORKORDER.REPORTDATE, 
    WORKORDER.ACTFINISH, 
    (WORKORDER.LOCATION + ' ' +LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION) LOC_DESC
FROM WORKORDER 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATIONS ON WORKORDER.LOCATION = LOCATIONS.LOCATION 
WHERE 
    WORKORDER.HISTORYFLAG = 0 
    AND WORKORDER.ISTASK = 0 
    AND WORKORDER.STATUS = 'COMP' 
    AND WORKORDER.STATUSDATE >= getdate() - 1 
    AND WORKORDER.LOCATION LIKE 'ABC%'
```

I would like to add an additional condition (probably in the WHERE clause) that would enable the following behavior:
- If the workorder WORKTYPE is 'PM' and the WOPRIORITY is 5, don't include it!
- If the workorder WORKTYPE is anything else, allow any priority

I'm not sure exactly what type of IF or CASE statement to put in the WHERE clause to specfically restrict priority 5 PM's. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

---

I may have found a solution! I have added the following line to the end of the WHERE clause:

```
AND (case when WORKORDER.WORKTYPE='PM' then WORKORDER.WOPRIORITY<>5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be thinking too hard about this...

```
WHERE NOT (WorkType = 'PM' AND WOPRIORITY = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! You were exactly right! I was overthinking it! (Writing my post here actually helped me realize that!)

Comment: You got credit for the answer since you answered the quickest!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't just `WHERE NOT (WORKTYPE = 'PM' AND WOPRIORITY = 5)` solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this line to your where clause :

```
    AND NOT (WORKORDER.WORKTYPE = 'PM' AND WORKORDER.WOPRIORITY = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do something like this:

```
 ... AND 1 = CASE WHEN WORKTYPE='PM' AND WOPRIORITY=5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ...
```

though in this case I don't see why you wouldn't just use simpler logic. Generally, CASE constructs like that are good for getting around SQL's wishy-washy evaluation order in general boolean expressions. Because it's good to avoid testing against null attributes, and because boolean evaluation order is not well defined, you use CASE to introduce a definite ordering of operations.